# Problems setting up active directory

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I just installed Windows Server 2012 onto my server and proceeded to install AD DS. And after days of trying, we just can not get Active directory to work! I installed everything the same way I did before (following a technet tutorial) , but now every time I try to open one of the active directory applications it comes up with an error:

> Naming information cannot be located because:
>
> The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. Contact your system administrator to verify that your domain is properly configured and is currently online

The events log is filled with constantly repeating messages:

id 14550

> The DFS Namespace service could not initialize cross forest trust information on this domain controller, but it will periodically retry the operation. The return code is the record data

id 6,67, 68, and 70 which both pretty much say the same thing:

> Certificate enrollment for Local system failed to load policy from policy servers with ID. The specified domain does not exist or could not be contacted.

and id 1129

> The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient condition. A success message would be generated once the machine gets connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has successfully proceeded. If you do not see a success message for several hours, then contact your administrator.

It all seems to be complaining about connection issues, and that's what all the support cases seem to point to also. But I don't see how that can be true if it is the domain controller, and its connected to the internet perfectly fine also

This is the  only DC (and will be for a little while until I can get another server), and it is also a DNS server.

And [here's the output of dcdiag](http://pastebin.com/i4D7TPk1)

Comment: We need more info on your environment.  Is this the only DC?  Is this DC also a DNS Server?  What are the DC's client DNS Settings?  What is the output of "Dcdiag /v"?

Comment: one second, I'll fix it. Sorry about that.

Comment: You say that you installed AD DS, my apologies but did you in fact run DCPROMO?

Comment: I used the domain controller promotion wizard through server manager.

Comment: OK. Assuming you installed DNS during DCPROMO, is the server pointing to itself for DNS? Alternately, if you're using another DNS server to support AD are the appropriate A and SRV records present? Do the AD DNS zones exist? Is the server pointing to the appropriate server for DNS?

Comment: Yes it is pointing to itself for DNS, and the zones exist. It only has Forward lookup zones thought does it need Reverse Lookup zones also?

Comment: Actually you don't DCPROMO in Server 2012. DCPROMO is just about dead, except for a couple of fringe cases that it's still useful for like IFM, etc. It's as simple as setting up your server with a static IP, and then doing `install-windowsfeature ad-domain-services` then `new-addsforest`. You don't even need to supply parameters; it will prompt you for everything it needs. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Right Ryan, that's what I did but it's not working.

Comment: AFter taking a closer look at the images in the tutorial, it seems like after doing the domain controller promotion I am missing 2 folders that the tutorial had: DomainDnsZones and ForestDnsZones aren't there.

Comment: I tried following instructions to manually add those but I failed getting an error that it can't contact the domain...

Comment: I just tried removing and reinstalling DNS and AD DS, no luck either. I even tried reinstalling the OS and it still hasn't worked.

Comment: Managed to fix it by formatting the hard drive completely and starting from scratch.